# Vista Startup - Cannot Find the File Specified

Tags: windows-vista, boot

Yesterday I restarted my laptop because my Wi-Fi catcher wasn't working correctly, and when the computer reached the login screen, instead of showing my user account it said "Cannot find the file specified". I rebooted and ran the Startup Repair and Memory Diagnostics but nothing showed up. I also took the battery out for a minute and tried again but still no luck. The weird thing is that I cannot even boot into safe mode, it still shows the same error.

I don't remember downloading or opening anything suspicious recently, and I have 3 different cleaners/anti-malware programs as well that I usually run about once a week. I did go into the registry recently but I didn't modify or delete anything as I was only checking to see if I had a certain key in it.

I have a Dell laptop running Vista Home Basic SP2.

If I have to I can reinstall the OS with the CD or even take it to Best Buy but I'd rather try and fix it first.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it show after the error message. I mean does it hang or ask you to restart or lets to login to a different user account?

Comment: @AbhishekGirish No it's just button that says ok. When you click it or hit enter it basically blacks out for a second and then comes back. I'm assuming it's checking again for an account.

Comment: You can try inserting the Windows setup CD and restoring the state of your computer to an earlier date.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish That's my problem, I don't create a lot of restore points except when Vista does it automatically for a Service Pack update, and the last time that happened was right after I reinstalled the OS about a year ago.

Comment: Windows does create restore points at other times, such as before installing updates or apps. Did you find no restore points listed or did you assume there wouldn't be any?

Comment: @AbhishekGirish I looked. It looks like I'm gonna have to reinstall the OS. I have no idea what happened, and it must be bad if even safe mode doesn't work. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem in the future, I finally solved it by using old Microsoft XP knowledge.

Do a hard shutdown of your pc/laptop and then hold F8 while the computer is in the pre-loading process. A screen will come up with quite a few boot options; simply select boot last known good configuration.